# Angular 2 Observable breaks when adding callback logic

Tags: angular

I have the following login function:

```
 login(payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, payload)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

I call it like this on login and it works fine:

```
this.sk_auth.login(this.loginCreds).subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
      //here we can do anything we want with the response.
     if(response.success){
       sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
       sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.user)); 

    });
```

The problem is that I need to do something before I return the response. I tried this:

```
login(payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, payload)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res)=>{
         //do some stuff...
      })
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

When I add the second map the observable response no longer gets returned to the subscribe on the login component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have a return statement in the second map? Since you're using the curly bracket notation, there's no automatic return from that function like your previous more simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Its resolved. I was't returning the result in the second map function. (Slapping my forehead!)

```
login(payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, payload)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res)=>{
         //do some stuff...
         return res;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use operator 'do' You can read about basic rxjs operators for angularJS developer familiar with $q in my post. [$Q map to RxJS](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do more than 1 thing, you can use promises.

```
login(payload: Object) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, payload)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .then(this.doSomeStuff)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || [];
}
private doSomeStuff(body: any) {
  //do some stuff...
  return theStuff;
}
private handleError(error: any) {
  Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```